# Unable to resolve pending changes after renaming a folder

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I renamed a folder correctly in Visual Studio (shows as a move) but after merging down to the parent branch, I've now got numerous conflicts that I'm unable to resolve.

They show up in the 'Resolve Conflicts' window with the Description, 'You have a conflicting pending change.' against each conflict.

[image]

If I try to resolve by taking the server or the local version, they disappear but reappear seconds later.

I've tried `tf undo * /recursive` from the parent folder but that reports 'no pending changes to undo'  and I've tried delete the entire folder and 'Get Specific Version..' and forced over-write but nothing I do can get rid of these conflicts.

Comment: Did you rename the folder and the merge in one changeset? This might cause to confuse TFS, because he don't know which change to handle first. Also it is not useful to move and rename files/folders in one changeset. This works fine, but doing merges or migrations, it could end in such errors.

Comment: The move was a seperate changest. I think someone else has left a merge outstanding, if I set deleted files to be visible the folder that's been deleted seems to have a 'merge,delete' lock on it by another user.  I'm just tyring to establish if that's the cause, but the office is empty because of snow here (Yorkshire, UK)

Comment: If you see the 'merge,delete' as a changeset, than this merge is done, but if it is a pending change this could be your problem. Is it the same folder you want to merge? Because than you would try to move a deleted folder or the pending change will delete a folder, that is removed (if your change would be checked in). You can check for pending changes easily by using TFS Sidekicks (http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up deleting the workspace and re-getting the latest code before trying the merge again, and everything worked fine.  I'm guessing there was some sort of corruption in the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me: 
1. Exit Visual Studio
2. Open a command window and navigate to the folder: "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\"
3. Navigate to the sub folders for every version and delete the sub folder "cache" and its contents
4. Restart Visual Studio and connect to TFS.
5. Undo/Get Latest Version.

Comment: In addition to this, I had to delete the offending file, go into source control, then undo the pending change there. Was able to then redownload file make my changes and check in.

Answer (score 1):

Try undoing any dependent changes first, retrace your steps that you did in the merge. Don't try to undo all changes at once. It's likely there are dependent changes that need to be undone before you can undo the one in question.
e.g. If you have renamed/deleted files or a folder then undoing the rename may cause a clash with some other folder or files, so undo the merge of those dependent files/solders first, then try undoing the renamed/deleted ones.
I have found that if you try to do rename, edit and merge in one go it will get confused and when you go to undo it there will be conflicts unless you undo the conflicting changes first.